# Dreamweaver code view highlighting

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, dreamweaver

I'm getting rather sick of Dreamweaver. It decides some PHP is invalid and then picks a random colour to display the code in, instead of the normal syntax highlighting. I've Googled the problem of course, but can't find a way of turning this behaviour off.

The particular thing it's doing at the minute is this:

*Invalid markup Marked invalid because it's not the correct format for an HTML tag.
Use the Code View to fix the source code.*

The file is a ridiculously basic CodeIgniter controller as follows:

```
<?php
class Controller2 extends Controller {

    function Controller2()
    {
        parent::Controller();   
    }

    function index()
    {
        echo "TEST";
        #$this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

Inserting a carriage return at the end of line 1 returns the code to normal syntax highlighting until you do something else with it.

How do I turn off this 'feature' of Dreamweaver's?

Comment: I am wondering now if the reason was the lack of a closing ?> PHP tag, but it would still be nice to get rid of this feature from Dreamweaver.

Comment: yea. when DW does this to me, i realize it's my fault.

try closing your php tag. Also, one thing that annoys the hell out of me, if after a put a { in a js file, and press enter, there will be TONS of whitespace before the cursor. If anyone knows a solution to this, shoot :)

Comment: Adding `?>` to PHP-only files is something which it is actually banned in the Zend coding style... http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html#coding-standard.php-file-formatting.general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View > Code View Options > Highlight Invalid Code